# Android - Setting in-call volume has no effect

Tags: android, skype, android-audiomanager

My app launches a Skype call. Before the call is made I want to ensure the in-call volume is set to 75% of the maximum. This is what I've tried ...

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
int curVol = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
int maxVol = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
int newVol = <do some calculations>
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, newVol, 0);
<launch Skype call>
```

However, I'm finding that:

- getStreamVolume always returns 5, irrespective of that the volume is actually set to on the device
- setStreamVolume has no effect, no matter what value for newVol I use

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong? Also, anyone any idea of what the 'flags' argument for setStreamVolume is used for? It's not described in the API docs.

Thanks

Damian.